# Need help performing (multiplication) operations on object arrays using Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, function, data-structures

I need to know how to divide values from a particular column from two different object arrays.
Price, Cash, cid are the arguments we provide while calling the function cash_register().
cid is the total amount of currency notes each that exist in the register currently. price is the amount to be paid and cash is the cash given by the customer.
First array consists of the total amount of currency units i have and the second array contains the actual value of each currency unit. In my **denom function** I'm trying to get an array which will show how many of each currency units I own.
Currency units here stand for Penny, Nickel, Dime, Quarter etc. in my cid variable.

I'm unsure if I've used the map function incorrectly or if i should try a different method or should I just convert my object arrays instead of just retrieving the values.

```js
//INPUT - 2 D array of cash with the total amount left

var cid = [
  ["PENNY", 1.01],
  ["NICKEL", 2.05],
  ["DIME", 3.1],
  ["QUARTER", 4.25],
  ["ONE", 90],
  ["FIVE", 55],
  ["TEN", 20],
  ["TWENTY", 60],
  ["ONE HUNDRED", 100]
];

function cash_register(cid, price, cash) {
  //curr_units defines the amount of each currency unit
  var curr_units = {
    "PENNY": 0.01,
    "NICKEL": 0.05,
    "DIME": 0.1,
    "QUARTER": 0.25,
    "ONE": 1,
    "FIVE": 5,
    "TEN": 10,
    "TWENTY": 20,
    "ONE HUNDRED": 100
  };

  var change = cash - price;

  // only values of cid
  var new_cid = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < cid.length; i++) {
    new_cid.push(cid[i][1]);
  }

  // can't figure this part out. Need to divide cid values by curency unit values
  var getDenom = function(new_cid, curr_units) {
    return Object.values(curr_units).map((x) => (new_cid[x] / x));
  }

}
```

The output I need is an object array with key value pairs of currency unit and the no of denominations of each.

```
denom={
  "PENNY": 101,
  "NICKEL": 41,
  "DIME": 31,
  "QUARTER": 17,
  "ONE": 90,
  "FIVE": 11,
  "TEN": 2,
  "TWENTY": 3,
  "ONE HUNDRED": 1};
```

Comment: How do you call the `cash()` function?  `var change=cash-price;` cash here is undefined

Comment: I formatted the code a bit to make it easier to see all the things inside the function and added it to a snippet - but really nothing runs the function

Comment: Sorry I messed up while pasting part of my code here. I've made the necessary changes and added some extra details on the purpose of the variables and functions @MarkSchultheiss

Comment: You trying to access to your array with the value and not the key `new_cid[x]`. x is the value [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values). You should use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: If none of these answers provide a viable solution you should add more notes as to why not.  If they do you should accept the one that does by checking the check mark to the left of them

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do this:

Use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) instead of 
[Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

```
// Fill the array like this [key:value]
for (var i = 0; i < cid.length; i++)
{
  new_cid[cid[i][0]] = cid[i][1];
}

// Map on the keys and not the values
var getDenom = function(new_cid, curr_units)
{
  return Object.keys(curr_units).map(x => new_cid[x] / curr_units[x]);
}
```

**Edit** : 
Another solution with `Array.forEach`, simpler than using `for`  :

No need of `new_cid`

```
var result = [];
cid.forEach(item => {
  result[item[0]] = item[1] / curr_units[item[0]];
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: But I need to retreive Object.value(curr_units) because I need to divide that with the corressponding cid values. Also, the for loop doesn't give me a proper output.

Comment: This way mapping on keys should associate curr_units key with the same new_cid key and do the divide by the corresponding values. It is not what you want ? _x represent the same key on each array._

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using one simple loop.

```js
var cid = [
    ["PENNY", 1.01],
    ["NICKEL", 2.05],
    ["DIME", 3.1],
    ["QUARTER", 4.25],
    ["ONE", 90],
    ["FIVE", 55],
    ["TEN", 20],
    ["TWENTY", 60],
    ["ONE HUNDRED", 100]
];

var curr_units = {
    "PENNY": 0.01,
    "NICKEL": 0.05,
    "DIME": 0.1,
    "QUARTER": 0.25,
    "ONE": 1,
    "FIVE": 5,
    "TEN": 10,
    "TWENTY": 20,
    "ONE HUNDRED": 100
 };
 
function calculate(cid, units) {
    var total = {};
    
    cid.forEach(val => {
     total[val[0]] = Math.round(val[1] / units[val[0]]);
    });
    
    return total;
}
```

Yields:

```
{
  "PENNY": 101,
  "NICKEL": 41,
  "DIME": 31,
  "QUARTER": 17,
  "ONE": 90,
  "FIVE": 11,
  "TEN": 2,
  "TWENTY": 3,
  "ONE HUNDRED": 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With an array of objects with a key/value pair you can address it simply.  Here I present a slightly verbose example so you can tell what is happening.

```js
//INPUT - 2 D array of cash with the total amount left

var cid = [
  ["PENNY", 1.01],
  ["NICKEL", 2.05],
  ["DIME", 3.1],
  ["QUARTER", 4.25],
  ["ONE", 90],
  ["FIVE", 55],
  ["TEN", 20],
  ["TWENTY", 60],
  ["ONE HUNDRED", 100]
];
var getDenom = function(ncid, units) {
  let ret = Object.keys(units).map(function(key, index) {
    // console.log("key:",key);// the name like PENNY
    // console.log("ukey:",units[key]); // the value like 0.01
    // console.log("nkey:",ncid[index]); // the value like `1.01
    let p = {
      k: key,
      val: Math.round(ncid[index] / units[key])
    };
    // console.log(p);
    return p;
  });
  return ret;
};

function cash(cid, price, change) {
  //curr_units defines the amount of each currency unit
  var curr_units = {
    "PENNY": 0.01,
    "NICKEL": 0.05,
    "DIME": 0.1,
    "QUARTER": 0.25,
    "ONE": 1,
    "FIVE": 5,
    "TEN": 10,
    "TWENTY": 20,
    "ONE HUNDRED": 100
  };

  // why redefine change and what is cash? commented out as it is unknown what the intent is
  // var change = cash - price;

  // only values of cid
  var new_cid = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < cid.length; i++) {
    new_cid.push(cid[i][1]);
  }

  let den = getDenom(new_cid, curr_units);
  //console.log("den:",den);
  let robj = {};
  den.forEach(function(element) {
    robj[element.k] = element.val
  });
  // console.log("den:", den); // same as "ret" above
  //console.log('robj:', robj);
  return robj;
}
let newObj = cash(cid, 0, 0);
console.log("newObj:", newObj);
```